# How do I make a JavaScript variable completely immutable?

Tags: javascript, immutability, var

I've heard similar questions, but not the answer that I wanted;
I do not count const because:
1). 
it doesn't actually make it immutable, it only makes the reference immutable
2).
it messes with the scope, and I want it to work outside the block, too
3).
not all browsers support it yet

```
 {
     const hello = ["hello", "world"];
     hello.push("!!!");
     console.log(hello);//outputs "hello", "world", "!!!"
 }
 //and it doesn't, and shouldn't, work here
     console.log(hello);
```

Comment: `const hello = Object.freeze(["hello", "world"]);`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) for this (obviously only on `object`s).

```js
const hello = Object.freeze(["hello", "world"]);

// hello.push("!!!");
// will throw "TypeError: can't define array index property past the end of an array with non-writable length"

// hello.length = 0;
// will fail silently

// hello.reverse();
// will throw "TypeError: 0 is read-only"

// hello[0] = "peter";
// will fail silently
```

From MDN:

> The `Object.freeze()` method freezes an `object`. A frozen object can no longer be changed; freezing an object prevents new properties from being added to it, existing properties from being removed, prevents changing the enumerability, configurability, or writability of existing properties, and prevents the values of existing properties from being changed. In addition, freezing an object also prevents its prototype from being changed. `freeze()` returns the same object that was passed in.

However, there is no keyword to define a completely immutable variable without using `Object.freeze` or `Object.seal` on the variable's value.

For a less restrictive approach Javascript also has [`Object.seal()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal).

Answer (score 4):

Just use [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

```
const immutableArray = Object.freeze([1,2,4])
```

Comment: thanks, but that only works for objects! how can it work for any data type?

Comment: `const name = Object.freeze(<anything>)` works just fine. `<anything>` can be an Array, an Object, a Number, String, Boolean or anything else. Try it in your browser.

Comment: Yeap. Sorry I missed your comment. But yes, `Object.freeze` accepts any reference type. Remember that almost everything is an object in js (except primitives)

Comment: @Dupocas Aren't Arrays, Strings, Booleans, Numbers, etc, primitives?  nevertheless, it does indeed work on anything, it would just be pointless, now that I think about it: `Object.seal(4)` for e.g.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it without const is to use `Object.defineProperty`, and like I wanted, it behaves like `var` in terms of scope:

```
{
    Object.defineProperty(typeof global === "object" ? global : window, "PI", {
        value:        Object.seal(3.141593),
        enumerable:   true,
        writable:     false,
        configurable: false
    });
}
console.log(PI); // 3.141593
```

The only problem is that it that it doesn't throw an error outside of strict mode.